# Cursor search commands in probe window on PSpice

Tags: pspice

I'm using PSpice, and when I am in the probe window, and I want to mark a specific point in the probe window, I'm using
Trace->Cursor->Search Command
and the I'm typing `sf le (10)`
This command searching for the closest Y value to the cursor that equal to 10.
So my question is where can I find all the search commands that possible?
I searched in google, and the following tutorials

- http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~jan/spice/PSpice_UserguideOrCAD.pdf
- http://www.it.uom.gr/project/digital/pspcbscs.pdf

and more..  but couldn't find list of all the commands that are possible.

Does anyone seen this kind of tutorial or cheat sheet??

Regards
Matt

Comment: here : http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~jan/spice/PSpice_UserguideOrCAD.pdf on page 92, they say "see this on the online PSpice help" about these commands. Couldn't find what help they were referring to though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it [here](http://www.ee.kau.se/utbildning/OrCAD/psphlp.pdf), page 207 :

> Search [direction] [/start_point/] [#consecutive_points#]
>   [(range_x[,range_y])] [for] [repeat:]

there's also detail on each option of the command.

I guess in your command, sf is an alias for "search forward"

Hope this helps